# How can I recursively delete all files of a specific extension in the current directory?

Tags: command-line, files, rm, batch

How do I safely delete all files with a specific extension (e.g. `.bak`) from current directory and all subfolders using one command-line? Simply, I'm afraid to use `rm` since I used it wrong once and now I need advice.

Comment: Related post - [How do I recursively delete directories with wildcard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23576/221891)

Answer (score 1464, accepted):

You don't even need to use `rm` in this case if you are afraid. Use `find`:

```
find . -name "*.bak" -type f -delete
```

But use it with precaution. Run first:

```
find . -name "*.bak" -type f
```

to see exactly which files you will remove.

Also, **make sure that `-delete` is the last argument** in your command. If you put it before the `-name *.bak argument`, **it will delete everything**.

See [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`man rm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) for more info and see also this related question on SE:

- [How do I remove all .pyc files from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/785519/2353900)

Comment: How's this different from `rm *.bak`?

Comment: @Bolt64 Your `rm *.bak` will not work for subdirectories.

Comment: With default settings `rm *.bak` will only delete all files ending with .bak in the current directory. TO also do things in subdirectories you either needed to fiddle with globs, use the -r option or use the find example.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't realize that.

Comment: You might want to add a '-print` to the second example. If you do not specify this then printing is the default, but explicitly stating it is a good idea in case you ever move to an OS which has different defaults.  (Same with the `.` which was mentioned. If you leave that out then some find binaries will assume `.` and some will complain about invalid syntax.

Comment: @Hennes Be careful with `rm -r *.bak`! It also removes directories ending in `.bak` with all their content.

Comment: True. Without the -r it prints a nice warning. (at least on FreeBSD with bash where I tested it). And maybe we should mention rm's `-i` flag since it will answer the key problem of the OP: "Not feeling safe with rm".

Comment: More generally, you can use e.g. `find . -name "*.bak" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 gvfs-trash`. (The `-print0` and the `-0` switch to xargs are important if your filenames might contain spaces or newlines.) Again, it's a good idea to first run just `find . -name "*.bak" -type f` so you can see what's going to be trashed.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, `rm -r *.bak` would delete directories suffixed by `.bak` only if these directories are empty, correct ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana No, *with all their content*.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu How can I do the same for two different types of files (for example `*.png` & `*.jpg`) without running the command twice?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam `find . -name "*.png" -or -name "*.jpg" -type f` or `find -regex ".*\.\(png\|txt\)" -type f`

Comment: @MohammedArif If you didn't observed yet, you are on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/), not on askwin7.com :)

Comment: OMG, didn't observe it at all :)

Thanks Radu to remind me.

Comment: **Make sure** that `-delete` is the last argument in your command. If you put it before the `-name *.bak` argument, *it will delete everything.*

Comment: Thanks @RaduRădeanu. In my opinion, for passing many wildcards, it is cumbersome to do `-or -name *.xyz` for the many different patterns. On windows, it is simply: `del /S *.txt *.log *.tmp *.ttx *.dox *.exe`

Comment: The precautionary advice is the best part :) Dry run to confirm the files before the actual `delete`.

Comment: You might want to use `-iname "*.bak"` for a **case-insensitive** match, to get rid of `.BAK` files as well.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu  Still a great answer after all these years! On my own system I add another safety net in this deletion which is the option `-mtime +90`. Perhaps this might be useful in your answer, even as a footnote?

Comment: +1 for the `-delete` warning!

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: I can't seem to make this work when wanting to delete *.volume dirs with `find . -name "*.volume" -type d -delete`. Using `find . -name "*.volume" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -rd` fixes the problem... is it the dir extension that mangles with the -delete option?

Answer (score 69):

First run the command `shopt -s globstar`. You can run that on the command line, and it'll have effect only in that shell window. You can put it in your `.bashrc`, and then all newly started shells will pick it up. The effect of that command is to make `**/` match files in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively (by default, `**/` means the same thing as `*/`: only in the immediate subdirectories). Then:

```
rm **/*.bak
```

(or `gvfs-trash **/*.bak` or what have you).

Comment: Thanks works ️️❤️

Comment: Not working in WSL with git bash. Says "rm: cannot remove '**/*.md': No such file or directory
"

Comment: @MarianKlühspies That just means there are no matching files.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' but there were matching files in sub directories. I've used `find . -name '*.md' -type f -delete` afterwards and deleted them successfully

Answer (score 61):

```
find . -name "*.bak" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! While this is a perfectly valid answer I don't think there's any advantage in using this instead of the `-delete` flag of `find`. More information can be found in the [GNU manuals entry for deleting files with find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html).

Comment: you are probably right, it's just an alternative solution, perhaps more raw ;)

Comment: This is not just an alternative but an example how other commands can be combined together with the pipe '|'. +1

Comment: This alternative solutions work on other environments that lack -delete (like cygwin)

Comment: I think this is the best answer here.

Comment: I'm on a legacy Unix HP UX 10.20 system. I was looking for an answer for this post question and landed here.

I don't have the `-delete` flag for the `find` command.
Instead what I did was just this:
`find /path/to/dir -name "*.bak" -type f | xargs rm`

Worked great for my need.

Comment: My find had no -delete, so this one was perfect

Comment: Worked best for me because I could easily augment for directories!

Comment: This will work easily for directories two with some changes, even for filled ones +1

Answer (score 26):

Deleting files is for me not something you should use `rm` for. Here is an alternative:

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs     # install a tool that allows you to put stuff in the trash
alias "trash"="gvfs-trash"    # you can also put this in .bash_aliases or simply use the command without alias
trash *.bak                   # trash the files (thus moving them to the trash bin)
```

As Flimm states in the comments:

> The package `trash-cli` does the same thing as `gvfs-trash` without the dependency on gvfs.

So:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

You don't need to make an alias for this, because the `trash-cli` package provides a command `trash`, which does what we want.

As Eliah Kagan makes clear in extensive comments, you can also make this recursive using `find`. In that case you can't use an alias, so the commands below assume you have installed `trash-cli`. I summarise Eliah's comments:

This command finds and displays all `.bak` files and symlinks anywhere in the current directory or its subdirectories or below.

```
find . -name '*.bak' -xtype f
```

To delete them, append an `-exec` with the `trash` command:

```
find . -name '*.bak' -xtype f -exec trash {} +
```

`-xtype f` selects files and symlinks to files, but not folders. To delete .bak folders too, remove that part, and use `-execdir`, which avoids `cannot trash non-existent` errors for `.bak` files inside `.bak` directories:

```
find . -name '*.bak' -execdir trash {} +
```

Comment: "Don't use `rm` to delete things" is a controversial statement but I have to agree that it's often wiser to use something that will let you undo things.

Comment: The package `trash-cli` does the same thing as `gvfs-trash` without the dependency on `gvfs`.

Comment: I have edited it in the answer, next time feel free to do the edit yourself.

Comment: @don.joey This answer seems to say `find . -name "*.bak" -type f` displays what `trash *.bak` deletes. *Is that really what you mean?* You can move directories to the trash with [`trash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/trash.1.html) or [`gvfs-trash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gvfs-trash.1.html), but `trash *.bak` will only moves files and directories whose names end with `.bak` and that reside immediately in the current directory. The shell expands `*.bak`, so `trash *.bak` won't affect `.bak` files in subdirectories not themselves named `.bak`.

Comment: @EliahKagan good spot. Yes, in this case `ls .*bak` would be better. Or do you have an alternative that makes `trash` recursive?

Comment: @don.joey Yes `ls *.bak` (which I think you mean) lists what `trash *.bak` trashes. `find . -name '*.bak' -xtype f -exec trash {} +` trashes all `.bak` files anywhere under `.`. It can't use an alias, so install `trash-cli` or write `gvfs-trash` instead. [Here's an example.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25740135/) `-xtype f` selects files and symlinks to files, but not folders. To delete `.bak` *folders* too, use `find . -name '*.bak' -execdir trash {} +`, which avoids `cannot trash non existent` errors for `.bak` files inside `.bak` directories. Please feel free to use any of this in your answer.

Comment: @EliahKagan much appreciated! have incorporated them, feel free to edit and make it a community wiki if that helps

Comment: Excellent idea having a trash option by command line. For those who do not, having an alias such as in bash/zsh: alias rm='rm -i' (same for mv or maybe even rmdir) is often enough to issue a 'are you really sure you want do delete this?' on the command line before rm destroys anything.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to delete all files of a certain type, but only 1 folder "deep" from the current folder:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.log" -type f -delete
```

**-maxdepth 2** because the current directory "**.**" counts as the first folder.

Answer (score 6):

## Quick Answer:

- Delete all files with the considered name or postfix recursively:

  `find . -name '*.pyc' -type f -delete`
- Delete all directories with the considered name recursively:

  ```
  find ~ -path '*/__pycache__/*' -delete‍‍‍
  find ~ -type d -name '__pycache__' -empty -delete‍‍‍
  ```

  Somewhat less tightly controlled, but in a single line:

  ```
  find ~ -path '*/__pycache__*' -delete
  ```

---

[**NOTE**]:

`d` is directory option and `f` is file option.

Answer (score 3):

If in case you want to check the list before you delete the files, you can echo it.

```
find . -name "*.bak" -type f | xargs echo rm -rf
```

This will list out the search results that are piped to rm command via xargs.
Once you are sure about the list you can drop the echo in above command.

```
find . -name "*.bak" -type f | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: its a good practice to add `-print0 | xargs -0` to handle cornercase filenames, example `test's` gives you `xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option` or filenames with newlines will break.

Answer (score 2):

You can list all the files with that extension first before you use `rm`
For example,

```
ls *.bak
```

If you get only the files that you want to delete then you can use the `rm`

```
rm *.bak
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you are confident that all your files of a particular extension (eg. `.bak`) has to be deleted, just use:

```
rm -ir *.bak
```

It will give you a prompt:

```
rm: remove regular file 'example.bak'?
```

Answer the prompt with a `y` for Yes and `n` for No

Comment: This isn't a correct answer to the question unfortunately. What you are suggesting will only delete `.bak` files in the current folder and any directories named `*.bak` which is almost certainly not what you want. It won't touch files named `*.bak` in subdirectories

Comment: My aim is not to delete a file name `*.bak` but to delete all the files with extension `.bak`. And for that the above command is. And for other file extensions we can just change the `.bak`