# How to delete all files of a specefic name from /?

Tags: command-line

I want to delete all files named typhoon.svg from / partition.
How to do that via command line?

Comment: What... you mean all files with that name in ANY directory?

Comment: Tried sudo rm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo find / -name "typhoon.svg" -type f -delete
```

See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/377438/147044) for some more explanations.

Comment: I usually do a "dry run" with find before I pipe it to delete, mainly because I am prone to typos. If the output looks good, repeat command with bash history and deletne.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Exactly, for this I gave as reference the link from the answer. ...In this case, run first: `find / -name "typhoon.svg" -type f`