# How to copy an entire directory except one file in each sub-directory via terminal?

Tags: command-line, cp

I have a folder named 'Java' which has 20 sub folders ('Day-01' to 'Day-20'). Each sub folder has one or two '.wav' files along with few other files. I want to copy the entire directory except the '.wav' files via terminal. How do I do this?

Comment: You can copy everything then [delete the .wav files by extension in that folder and subfolders](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377438/how-can-i-recursively-delete-all-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-the-current-di)

Comment: copy of [See this solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41693/how-to-copy-some-but-not-all-files/41696#41696)

Comment: @parto the op probably wants to avoid the time delay in copying the same (maybe large) audio file 20 times when they don't need to

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `rsync` with the `--exclude` option to exclude to `.wav` files from copying:

```
rsync -av --exclude='*.wav' /path/to/Java /out/dir
```

**Example:**

```
/foobar/Java% tree
.
├── day-01
│   ├── 01.sh
│   ├── 01.txt
│   └── 01.wav
├── day-02
│   ├── 02.sh
│   ├── 02.txt
│   └── 02.wav
├── day-03
│   ├── 03.txt
│   └── 03.wav
├── day-04
│   └── 04.txt
└── day-05
    └── 05.wav

/foobar/out% rsync -av --exclude='*.wav' ../Java .
sending incremental file list
Java/
Java/day-01/
Java/day-01/01.sh
Java/day-01/01.txt
Java/day-02/
Java/day-02/02.sh
Java/day-02/02.txt
Java/day-03/
Java/day-03/03.txt
Java/day-04/
Java/day-04/04.txt
Java/day-05/

sent 564 bytes  received 158 bytes  1,444.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

/foobar/out% tree
.
└── Java
    ├── day-01
    │   ├── 01.sh
    │   └── 01.txt
    ├── day-02
    │   ├── 02.sh
    │   └── 02.txt
    ├── day-03
    │   └── 03.txt
    ├── day-04
    │   └── 04.txt
    └── day-05
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you so much for the beautiful explanation. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @optimist if the answer solved your question, please accept this answer as a valid solution by clicking the grey checkmark next to the up and down arrows. Thank you for cooperation and welcome to AskUbuntu !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is proably to use rsync:

```
rsync -avz --exclude "*.wav" SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR
```