# Delete certain files with find in subdirectories only

Tags: find

I want to delete certain files within my subfolders but not in the current folder. `find` offers a neat method to do that:

[How can I recursively delete all files of a specific extension in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377438/how-can-i-recursively-delete-all-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-the-current-di?newreg=822d66a515f1450c8ca26674f15ff301)

for example

```
find . -name "*.bak" -type f -delete
```

but so far I only found instructions on how to delete everything in the current + all subfolders. Is there a way to perform this action only on the subfolders without `cd` into each subfolder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-mindepth 2`

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name "*.bak" -type f -delete
```