# Remove bulk files

Tags: command-line, bash, uninstall, delete

I need to remove all *.html files.
But, I have a parent folder that has so many child folders in it and an HTML file is present in every single child folder.
I can able to remove files by visiting each child's folder. But, I need to remove every HTML file directly from a parent folder

Comment: In addition to the answer already provided below, there is another way of doing it, with `-exec` or by piping to `rm`. In case of curiosity, here is the link: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167824/264443

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easiest method would be:

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' -delete
```

Do this from the directory where you want to start it from.

- `find` is a command to search for something
- `.` means from the directory you currently are in
- `f` means only search for files (`d` is for directories)
- and search for `name` ending in `.html`
- and find has an option that `delete`s them

Answer (score 1):

Before giving you a paste & run ready solution, there are some best practices and automation patterns for linux shell I would like to explain.
Same concepts are also applied in other IT fields:

- **divide & conquer**: split a problem into (isolated) parts to solve easily
- **separation of concerns**: here delete as command; find as query (CQRS)
- **pipes and filters**: the combination of best tools in a chain

#### Preview and pipe explained

Although the following recipe doesn't work for subdirectories (recursive), it illustrates a safe and modular method combining commands.

a) simple list and remove (preview first before action):

1. list all HTML files (just list, not revursive)
   `ls *.html`
2. then remove
   `rm *.html`

This is a **safety  first** approach. You preview and check the list of files before removing. When sure to proceed, just alter the command command.

Alternatively you can easily extend your workflow using **pipe**:

b) directly combined with *xargs*

```
ls *.html | xargs -r0 rm
```

The `xargs` is necessary because rm can't read from *stdin*.
See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307299/ddg#20307392

The `-r0` combines two options: `-0` will deal with cornercase filenames (having newlines, spaces or quotes like `it's done.html` in them) which more robustly are *separated by NUL character*. The `-r` will stop running if no input is given.

See:
[How can I recursively delete all files of a specific extension in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377438/how-can-i-recursively-delete-all-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-the-current-di/1191469#comment1993707_1191469)

and:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83712

#### Directly remove using *glob*

In some shells (bash since version 4, ksh, zsh) you can recursively remove files by using wildcards (*globstar*) in path.

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23576/how-do-i-recursively-delete-directories-with-wildcard

and [how to check/enable the globstar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/789378)

directly remove (dangerous):

```
rm **/*.html
```

This direct remove commands are dangerous because a small typo will have adverse impact. For example when accidentally inserted a blank in `rm *.html` it will become `rm * .html`. Unfortunately it will remove all files and may print the error of not finding second path '.html'.

#### Combine: find and remove

find (search for files in a directory hierarchy) and remove

1. using pipe (POSIX compliant: runs on more systems)

   `find . -type f -name "*.html" | xargs -r0 rm`
2. directly executing a following command (like the trash-cli, for later undelete):

   `find . -type f -name "*.html"  -exec trash {}`
3. directly using convenient actions (reliable: avoid spawning and race-conditions)

   `find . -type f -name "*.html" -print0 -delete`

**Explanation:**

- `-type f` only looks for regular files (not directory `d`, not symlinks)
- `-name` filters for names like the given pattern (can also be extended by `-or` and alternatively `-regex`)
- `-print0` prints the found file-paths (robustly NUL separated) before
- `-exec trash {}` executes the given command (here *trash*) with found file as argument (substitutes the curly braces)
- `-delete` directly removes the found file (performant because in the same process, although not as compatible with all find versions)

See notable warnings: [How can I recursively delete all files of a specific extension in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377438/how-can-i-recursively-delete-all-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-the-current-di)

More in the GNU manual for [Find, Deleting Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html)

#### Caution with mass delete: Linux has no built-in undelete

So first check what's found before deleting in batch.
Hence I recommend safety measures.

- interactive instead forcefully option: for *rm* `-i` instead of `-f`
- list or find first, then check, then delete (e.g. by appending pipes or first running *find* without action)
- using trash-folder tools that support later undo: like *trash-cli* or *gvfs-trash*

Comment: @steeldriver Notable advice against intuition: some commands only accept _arguments_ (thus `| xargs rm`). Also differs when interpreting a given _path_ (no recursion), but you can workaround expressing the path itself as kind of _vector_ using globs if supported by your shell Thanks for contributing!

Comment: OK they're *better* now - but there's really no need to use constructs like `ls *.html | xargs ...` when you can *more robustly* use `printf '%s\0' *.html | xargs -r0 ...`. Similarly the `find` version could use `-print0 | xargs -r0 rm` (although if you're going to use `find`, the accepted answer is better).